# How to find the index of an entire array in an array of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to find the indices of entire arrays in an array of arrays. So for the example arrays `a` and `b` below, I would like to know at which indices of `a` the subarrays in `b` can be found.

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[[1 ,2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]])
b = np.array([[[5, 6], [7, 8]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]])
```

Since `b` contains the subarrays `[[5, 6], [7, 8]]` and `[[1,2], [3,4]]` and since this corresponds to the second and first row of `a`, respectively I would like the solution to return `[1, 0]`.

I have tried using `np.where(b == a)` but this returns where the two arrays are the same as can be seen below:

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]),
 array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]))
```

Comment: `where` is only as good as the cond array, `a==b`.  Examine that, or any thing fancier before using `where`

Comment: Can `a` have subarrays that aren't in `b`, or `b` not in a `a`.  In you example the mapping is one to one.  Also what are the relative sizes?  We can, with `broadcasting` construct an == array that tests all against all, but such an array can be very large.  (a.shape[0],b..shape[0],2,2).  Then apply `all` to the (2,2) portion, resulting in (a.shape[0], b.shaoe[0])

Answer (score 0):

You can add `all(axis=1)` to `where`

```
np.where((a == b).all(axis=1))
# (array([0, 0], dtype=int64), array([0, 1], dtype=int64))
```

If you want just the first result add index

```
np.where((a == b).all(axis=1))[0]
# [0 0]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your reply! If I understand correctly, your code is still checking at which indices the two arrays are the same. However, I am trying to figure out the indices for which the subarrays in `b` occur in `a`. I have changed the example so it becomes more clear. If you also have an idea on how to achieve this, it would be great to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

```
res = []
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(b.shape[0]):
        if np.array_equal(a[i],b[j]):
            res.append(i)
res
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your suggestion! It seems to work but unfortunately, the arrays of the actual problem I am working on are very large such that it would take a lot of iterations to compute the result. Do you  know if there is a vectorized method to achieve this, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Assuming that every subarray of `a` is unique:

```
res = np.unique(np.concatenate((a,b)),axis=0,return_inverse=True)[1][len(a):]
```

So we identify each unique subarray and then we return the corresponding inverse index.

This solution will fail if:

- every subarray of `a` are not unique
- some subarray of `b` are not member of `a`

This solution will also work if:

- `b` contains some duplicate

**Solution 2:**

```
res = np.where(np.equal(a[:,None],b).all(axis=(2,3)).T)[1]
```

Here I use `np.equal()` in order to compare each subarray. I also add a new dimension to `a` so the two arrays can be broadcasted. Then we get rid of the dimension 2 and 3 with `all(axis=(2,3))` and finally we return the index with `np.where()`.